# UWP Grid RowSpan with ScroolViewer

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

If you paste this code in the mainpage of a new UWP app (or look at the 1st picture) you can see that the orange grid is taking more space than needed (`VerticalAlignment` is set to top). To make it work like it should, you have to set the 2nd row's height of this grid to `Auto` (see 2nd picture). The problem is that I want to give the extra space to the 2nd/last row and not to distribute it across all rows.
*Putting the controls in the left column inside their own grid works (obviously, because there is no rowspan) but I can't do that because when the screen narrows the stackpanel in the right column goes inside a row in the left column.*
The second problem is that if you click on the orange/green/yellow space, focus goes always to the textbox in the first row (yellow).

**UPDATE**: both problems are fixed without the scrollviewer but I clearly need it.

```
<Page
x:Class="App1.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App1"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ScrollViewer Background="DarkGreen" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Grid Background="DarkOrange" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Background="Yellow">
                <TextBlock Text="Title" />
                <TextBox Margin="20" />
            </StackPanel>
            <Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="DeepPink" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <ListView Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <ListView.Items>
                        <TextBlock Text="Item1" />
                    </ListView.Items>
                </ListView>
            </Grid>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Background="Blue" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="Title1" />
                    <GridView Margin="0,10,0,0">
                        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" MaximumRowsOrColumns="4" />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                        <GridView.Items>
                            <Rectangle Width="80" Height="80" Fill="White" />
                            <Rectangle Width="80" Height="80" Fill="White" />
                            <Rectangle Width="80" Height="80" Fill="White" />
                            <Rectangle Width="80" Height="80" Fill="White" />
                            <Rectangle Width="80" Height="80" Fill="White" />
                            <Rectangle Width="80" Height="80" Fill="White" />
                            <Rectangle Width="80" Height="80" Fill="White" />
                            <Rectangle Width="80" Height="80" Fill="White" />
                            <Rectangle Width="80" Height="80" Fill="White" />
                            <Rectangle Width="80" Height="80" Fill="White" />
                            <Rectangle Width="80" Height="80" Fill="White" />
                            <Rectangle Width="80" Height="80" Fill="White" />
                        </GridView.Items>
                    </GridView>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="Title2" />
                    <GridView Margin="0,10,0,0">
                        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" MaximumRowsOrColumns="4" />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                        <GridView.Items>
                            <Rectangle Width="80" Height="80" Fill="White" />
                            <Rectangle Width="80" Height="80" Fill="White" />
                            <Rectangle Width="80" Height="80" Fill="White" />
                            <Rectangle Width="80" Height="80" Fill="White" />
                            <Rectangle Width="80" Height="80" Fill="White" />
                            <Rectangle Width="80" Height="80" Fill="White" />
                            <Rectangle Width="80" Height="80" Fill="White" />
                            <Rectangle Width="80" Height="80" Fill="White" />
                            <Rectangle Width="80" Height="80" Fill="White" />
                            <Rectangle Width="80" Height="80" Fill="White" />
                            <Rectangle Width="80" Height="80" Fill="White" />
                            <Rectangle Width="80" Height="80" Fill="White" />
                        </GridView.Items>
                    </GridView>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

[image: rowspan]

Comment: So you want it like the 2nd picture?

Comment: I want like 1st picture but the orange grid should end like 2nd picture. I don't know why that extra space is added...to me this is a bug in the measure calculation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround. Since the first row is not going to expand or change, I set the first row's `MaxHeight` property equal to the actual height of the row at runtime.
For the second problem set the `IsTabStop` property of the scrollviewer to `True` as explained here:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/32e026dd-8338-4c19-a7d6-1bb8797044b3/first-input-control-in-the-scroll-viewer-is-always-getting-focused?prof=required